# Why can JavaScript handle timestamps beyond 2038?

Tags: javascript, php, year2038

As we know that all dates using Javascript Date constructor are calculated in milliseconds from 01 January, 1970 00:00:00 Universal Time (UTC) with a day containing 86,400,000 milliseconds. This implies that JS uses UNIX timestamp. I set my timer to a date beyond 2038 (say 14 Nov 2039) and run the script:

```
    <script>
      var d = new Date();
      alert(d.getFullYear()+" "+d.getMonth()+" "+d.getDate());
    </script>
```

It alerts 2039 10 14 successfully unlike PHP which prints "9 Oct, 1903 07:45:59"

How JS handles this? Explanation is appreciated as I am confused!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

32bit PHP uses 32bit integers, whose max value puts the last UNIX timestamp that can be expressed by them in 2038. That's widely known as the [Y2K38 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) and affects virtually all 32bit software using UNIX timestamps. Moving to 64bits or libraries which work with other timestamp representations (in the case of PHP the `DateTime` class) solves this problem.

Javascript doesn't have integers but only [floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_number), which don't have an inherent maximum value (but in return have less precision).

Comment: I don't understand why PHP wouldn't just use unsigned integers. That would effectively double the date range, right?

Comment: @Alex Because then you couldn't represent any dates *before* 1970, because PHP tries to keep types simple and doesn't want to bother programmers with the difference between signed and unsigned ints, because using *only* unsigned ints means you couldn't represent *any* negative numbers in PHP, because that would only extend the deadline by some ~70 years instead of solving it entirely.

Comment: @AlexW it is in order to hold dates prior to 1970 which is considered as an epoch in UNIX timestamp,right?

Comment: one more thing to ask @deceze, as a long int is 4 bytes and a float is also 4 bytes (although in C), what about JS while it uses float instead of int...?

Comment: @rosemary What about it? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @deceze i mean to say that a long int requires 4 byte whereas a float requires also 4 bytes.Then, had JS used int like that in PHP it would have same problem as that of PHP. But float is itself 4 byte long, confused,right?

Comment: @rosemary Please read the linked article about floats, or *any* article about floats, really. Ints are *exact* numbers, where `...00001` is "1", `...00010` is "2" etc, for all possible combinations of 32 bits. Floats on the other hand store numbers as an expression of a mantissa and an exponent, which allows them to express much larger numbers and scale both parts up or down as needed. But in return they cannot express many numbers *exactly*. Floating point rounding errors are a problem you have to content with.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript doesn't have integer numbers, only floating point numbers (details can be found in [the standards document](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)).

That means that you can represent some really large numbers, but at the cost of precision. A simple test is this:

```
i = 1384440291042
 => 1384440291042
i = 13844402910429
 => 13844402910429
i = 138444029104299
 => 138444029104299
i = 1384440291042999
 => 1384440291042999
i = 13844402910429999
 => 13844402910430000
i = 138444029104299999
 => 138444029104300000
i = 1384440291042999999
 => 1384440291043000000
i = 13844402910429999999
 => 13844402910430000000
```

As you can see the number is not guaranteed to be kept exact. [The outer limits of integer precision in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Example%3a_Using_Number_to_convert_a_Date_object) (where you will actually get back the same value you put in) is 9007199254740992. That would be good up until 285428751-11-12T07:36:32+00:00 according to my conversion test :)

The simple answer is that Javascript internally uses a larger data type than the longint (4 bytes, 32bit) that is used for the C style epoc ...

Comment: fun fact, `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` reports `9007199254740991` now in chrome. so this issue seems to be resolved already.

Answer (score 3):

It can. Try out `new Date(8640000000000000)`

> Sat Sep 13 275760 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)

Year 275760 is is a bit beyond 2038 :)

Read the spec section 15.9.1.1

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1

> A Date object contains a Number indicating a particular instant in
>   time to within a millisecond. Such a Number is called a time value. A
>   time value may also be NaN, indicating that the Date object does not
>   represent a specific instant of time.
>
> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970
>   UTC. In time values leap seconds are ignored. It is assumed that there
>   are exactly 86,400,000 milliseconds per day. ECMAScript Number values
>   can represent all integers from –9,007,199,254,740,992 to
>   9,007,199,254,740,992; this range suffices to measure times to
>   millisecond precision for any instant that is within approximately
>   285,616 years, either forward or backward, from 01 January, 1970 UTC.
>
> The actual range of times supported by ECMAScript Date objects is
>   slightly smaller: exactly –100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days
>   measured relative to midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970
>   UTC. This gives a range of 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds to
>   either side of 01 January, 1970 UTC.
>
> The exact moment of midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970 UTC
>   is represented by the value +0.

Comment: Worth noting that `new Date(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)` yields "Invalid Date".  But you can definitely use `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / 2`, which gets you through year 144,683 AD.  Hopefully that's good enough for most use cases, though I suppose you never know.  If there's any language that'll be around in year 144k AD, it'll be JavaScript! ☢️️‍

Comment: @mikermcneil True, but your answer is not accurate either, updated mine to represent the real limit :) Thanks for making me do it :D

Answer (score 2):

> This implies that JS uses UNIX timestamp.

Just a sidenote: Unix timestamp are seconds since 1970. JS time is milliseconds since 1970. So JS timestamp does not fit in a 32 bit int much earlier (but JS does not use 32 bit int for this)

Answer (score 1):

The year 2038 problem applies to signed 32 bit timestamps only, which PHP and some other systems use. A signed 32-bit timestamp's range runs out with the number of seconds in 2038.

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) (emphasis mine):

> The year 2038 problem may cause some computer software to fail at some point near the year 2038. **The problem affects all software and systems that both store system time as a signed 32-bit integer,** and interpret this number as the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on Thursday, 1 January 1970.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) The furthest time that can be represented this way is 03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038.[2] ... **This is caused by integer overflow.** The counter "runs out" of usable digits, "increments" the sign bit instead, and reports a maximally negative number (continuing to count up, toward zero). This is likely to cause problems for users of these systems due to erroneous calculations.

Storing a timestamp in a variable with a greater range solves the problem.